# Help! How do I draw this symbol in LaTeX?

Tags: circuitikz

[image]

How to draw this symbol (2 straight lines with an arc) in LaTeX? Really need help on this one. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX.SE!! What do you mean by "this symbol"? Do you only want the arrow, or adding the secant line with 2 straight lines?

Comment: Electronic device? Tikz? CircuiTikz? https://ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz

Comment: I'd like to draw the parallel lines with the arc on it. It is not available in the circuitikz manual.

Answer (score 1):

Like this? Just to be a starting point.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{%
startbutton/.pic = {%
\draw [very thick](0,0)--++(-90:1);
\draw [very thick](0,-2)coordinate(A)--++(-90:1);
\draw [very thick](A)--++(125:1.1)coordinate(B);
\draw [very thick]($(A)!0.45!(B)$)--++(180:0.75)coordinate(C);
\draw [very thick]($(A)!0.55!(B)$)--++(180:0.68)coordinate(D);
\tkzDrawArc[R,thick,fill,black]($(C)!0.5!(D)$, 4pt)(90,270)
}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic {startbutton};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to just make an arc instead of a semi circle? Thanks btw! This is already big help.

Comment: @Chowlo, try removing the fill command from the \tkzDrawArc line.

Comment: @Chowlo, your welcome. Remove `fill` command as said @N.F.Taussig and use `xshift`, such as `\tkzDrawArc[R,thick,black,xshift=1.25mm]($(C)!0.5!(D)$, 4pt)(90,270)`.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol is not in `circuitikz`, but you can build it if you insist... more or less.

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \ctikzset{bipoles/cuteswitch/thickness=0.5}
    \draw (0,0) to [cosw, name=sw] ++(0,2);
    \draw[thick, double, -{Arc Barb}] (sw.mid) -- ++(-0.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want a larger "double line" and/or (thanks @Sebastiano!) you have to do a few tricky things:

1. use a clip (well, [inverse clip](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/290508/38080)) to position the double line correctly and draw only the useful one;
2. redraw the switch to remove the ugly clip-line composition.

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
%
% Thanks to Symbol1, Paul Gaborit etc. at
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/290508/38080
%
\tikzset{
    clip even odd rule/.code={\pgfseteorule}, % Credit to Andrew Stacey
    invclip/.style={
        clip,insert path=
            [clip even odd rule]{
                [reset cm](-\maxdimen,-\maxdimen)rectangle(\maxdimen,\maxdimen)
            }
    }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \ctikzset{bipoles/cuteswitch/thickness=0.5}
    \begin{scope}
        \draw (0,0) to [cosw, name=sw, switches/scale=1.5] ++(0,2);
        % this "cuts out" from the path the triangle formed by the switch
        \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
            \clip[invclip] (sw.in) -- ($(sw.in)!2!(sw.mid)$) -- (sw.out) -- cycle;
        \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
        \draw[thick, double, double distance=4pt, -{Arc Barb[]}] (sw.mid) ++(0.2,0) -- ++(-1.3,0);
    \end{scope}
    %
    % redraw the switch to avoid the horrible junction!
    %
    \draw (0,0) to [cosw, name=sw, switches/scale=1.5] ++(0,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just an humble comment after my positive vote. Do you put the black straight line above instead in background?

Comment: Yes, to  simplify things (to have the anchor position). But you are right, wait a minute...

Comment: Very kind not to worry and no urgency was necessary. Mine was just a simple suggestion. :-) It was not necessary to include me in your addendum. So I get very emotional :-) and red in my face. :-)